# Is there queues and jobs like Laravel in Asp.net core?

Tags: c#, laravel, asp.net-core

Is there `queues` and `jobs` like Laravel in Asp.net core?

i want to use job and queue in .net core 3 but i do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core has some really good queuing systems, if you are beginner i would recommend [HandFire](https://www.hangfire.io/). It's simple to begin with, but only works with sql server in free tier. For redis support you will need to pay or use OpenSource [alternative](https://github.com/marcoCasamento/Hangfire.Redis.StackExchange).

Here some other queue implementations

1. [Coravel](https://github.com/jamesmh/coravel) - Laravel like queue
2. [Gofer](https://github.com/brthor/Gofer.NET)

Check some more awesome open source libraries [here](https://github.com/thangchung/awesome-dotnet-core).